# TWTRLogInCompletion block not executed when login with twitter app

Tags: twitter

I am using twitter authentication in my iOS app. Using TwitterCore (3.2.0) and TwitterKit 3.4.0 for authentication. My code is as below:

```
TWTRTwitter.sharedInstance().logIn { (session, error) in
                print("completion....")
            }
```

Now my problem is that when I don't install Twitter app on my iPhone, then this code works perfectly. But after installing Twitter app on my iPhone, this login method never execute the completion block.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! It might be helpful to know if you are getting any errors or if you are already authorized in the Twitter app when it is installed on your phone. The documentation for TwitterKit states that it checks for authorization in the Twitter app first so if you are already authorized in the Twitter app then there is no need to login. https://github.com/twitter/twitter-kit-ios/wiki/Log-In-With-Twitter

Comment: No I am not getting any error. Just the completion block is not executed where I need to place my app specific code after twitter authentication. Completion block doesn't execute even when my Twitter app is not authorised.